# JS loop through table and print text in column based on condition

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a simple table, and I need to print a text in a certain column based on condition over hidden columns. There are multiple rows as a record which have same TD ID. What I need to do is, to go through each row of table and check status1 (`gv-field-15-139`), status2 (`gv-field-15-140`) and status3 (`gv-field-15-141`). If one of this status (`gv-field-15-150`) is 'Completed' I want to print Completed in Status column. is it possible?

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     if(($('td#gv-field-15-139').text() == 'Completed') || ($('td#gv-field-15-
     140').text() == 'Completed') || ($('td#gv-field-15-141').text() == 'Completed') ) {
    $("td#gv-field-15-150").text('Completed');
    }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
       <th>Student Name</th>
       <th>Nationality</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>Status1</th>
       <th>Status2</th>
       <th>Status3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="gv-field-15-1">Student A</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-90">India</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-139">Completed</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="gv-field-15-1">Student B</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-90">China</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-139">Completed</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
       <td id="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

This only works for 1 row and when it becomes 2 row or more it doesn't work. Could you please show me a way to achieve this.

Comment: Do not duplicate ids, that's why you can't access past the first one. When JS finds an id, it naturally assumes that's the only tag with that id. Change your ids into classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop your `tr` except the first tr which has `th` and check `td`. Though you can achieve the solution to your problem with ids, its recommended to use class instead of ids.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trs = $('tr').not(':eq(0)');
    $.each(trs, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (($this.find('>td#gv-field-15-139').text() == 'Completed') || ($this.find('>td#gv-field-15-140').text() == 'Completed') || ($this.find('>td#gv-field-15-141').text() == 'Completed')) {
            $this.find(">td#gv-field-15-150").text('Completed');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Student Name</th>
   <th>Nationality</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Status1</th>
   <th>Status2</th>
   <th>Status3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="gv-field-15-1">Student A</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-90">India</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-139">Completed</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="gv-field-15-1">Student B</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-90">China</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-139">Completed</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="gv-field-15-1">Student B</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-90">China</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-139">Pending</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
   <td id="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is so simplistic it doesn't even have a need for jQuery, I also thought that it might be nicer to read if you broke the logic up a bit, i.e. rather than having an ugly & long looking if statement, I've implemented the `isComplete` function.

FYI. ID's are meant to be unique throughout the entire page, it may be a better idea to change them to classes if you can.

### Edit

After having looked at the **beautiful** solution produced by @HMR I thought I'd include some of the elegant code that was implemented into this solution, I can't take all the credit there!

```js
// Just short hand.
const $e = queryString => document.querySelectorAll(queryString);
const term = 'Completed';

// Returns a boolean.
const isComplete = td => td.textContent.replace(/\ /, '') === term;

// Some fallback function.
const fallback = () => console.log('Next...');

// Render the update(s).
const render = (v, t) => v.includes(true) ? t.textContent = term : fallback();

// Updates the relevant td tags.
const update = tr => {
  const tds = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('td'));
  const [, , , ...values] = tds.map(td => isComplete(td));
  const [, , td] = tds;
  render(values, td);
};

// Iterate over the relevant tr tags.
const loop = () => Array.from($e("table tr")).splice(1, ).forEach(tr => update(tr));

// Start the process.
loop();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Nationality</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Status1</th>
    <th>Status2</th>
    <th>Status3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="gv-field-15-1">Student A</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-90">India</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-139">Completed</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="gv-field-15-1">Student B</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-90">China</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-139">Completed</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="gv-field-15-1">Student C</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-90">China</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-139">Pending</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
    <td id="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use duplicate id's, you can use the index of the cells intead:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');
//take all rows except the header
const rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr')).slice(
  1,
);
rows.forEach((row) => {
  const cells = Array.from(
    row.querySelectorAll('td')
  );
  //get the 3rd cell
  const [, , toSet] = cells;
  //all values after 3rd cell
  const [, , ,...values] = cells.map(
    (cell) => cell.innerText.trim()//map to the innerText of the cell
  );
  if(values.includes('Completed')){
    toSet.innerHTML = 'Completed'
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Student Name</th>
   <th>Nationality</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Status1</th>
   <th>Status2</th>
   <th>Status3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Student A</td>
   <td>India</td>
   <td>xxx</td>
   <td>Completed</td>
   <td>Pending</td>
   <td>Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Student B</td>
   <td>China</td>
   <td>xxx</td>
   <td>Completed</td>
   <td>Pending</td>
   <td>Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Student C</td>
   <td>Not Completed</td>
   <td>xxx</td>
   <td>Pending</td>
   <td>Pending</td>
   <td>Pending</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Probably the best answer so far, very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues:

- You have duplicate IDs. ID must be unique. In your current code, you will always get first element with necessary ID. So you should use classes instead
- You are not looping. Since its a table and you have to handle each row, you have to loop over all rows and based on current row, you have to check/update necessary column's value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $tr = $('table tr');
  $.each($tr, function(index, tr) {
    if (
      ($('.gv-field-15-139', tr).text() == 'Completed') ||
      ($('.gv-field-15- 140', tr).text() == 'Completed') ||
      ($('.gv-field-15-141', tr).text() == 'Completed')
    ) {
      $(".gv-field-15-150", tr).text('Completed');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Nationality</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Status1</th>
    <th>Status2</th>
    <th>Status3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-15-1">Student A</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-90">India</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-139">Completed</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-15-1">Student B</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-90">China</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-150">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-139">Pending</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-140">Pending</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-141">Pending</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the rows in the table except the first row(and hence =>  `$('tr').length-1`).

`.eq()` function is used to access each element/text by index..

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       for(i=0;i<$('tr').length-1;i++){
           if( ($('td#gv-field-15-139').eq(i).text() == 'Completed') || ($('td#gv-field-15-140').eq(i).text() == 'Completed') || ($('td#gv - field - 15 - 141').eq(i).text() == 'Completed') ) {
            $("td#gv-field-15-150").eq(i).text('Completed');
           }
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

## `#ID`s Must Always be Unique

Having duplicated `#ids` makes HTML invalid, more importantly it cripples JS/jQ because it is expected that `#ids` are unique so once found, no efforts are made to continue for second occurrence of an `#id`.

---

### Changes

- All `#ids` have been changed to `.classes`
- The last 3 `<td>` of each row have a shared class: `.status`
- The 3rd `<td>` of each row has a new class: `.primary`

#### Reference

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

[`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

---

### Demo

**Three lines of code...that's all you need.**

```js
$('.status').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === 'Completed') {
    $(this).prevAll('.primary').text('Completed');
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Nationality</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Status1</th>
    <th>Status2</th>
    <th>Status3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-15-1">Student A</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-90">India</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-150 primary">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-139 status">Completed</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-140 status">Pending</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-141 status">Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-15-1">Student B</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-90">China</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-150 primary">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-139 status">Completed</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-140 status">Pending</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-141 status">Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-15-1">Student C</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-90">USA</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-150 primary">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-139 status">ERROR</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-140 status">Pending</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-141 status">Pending</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-15-1">Student D</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-90">France</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-150 primary">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-139 status">Pending</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-140 status">Pending</td>
    <td class="gv-field-15-141 status">Completed</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```